# JDBC connection to hive fails

Tags: java, hadoop

I'm trying to establish a `JDBC connection to Hive` so that I can query Hive tables using java API for `hive 0.13.1`. I've tried connecting to HiveServer1 and HiverServer2 but unable to make connection.
However locally within the box I am able to connect to the server using beeline command following it up with the command:

```
!connect jdbc://hive2://
```

once connection is established I am able to view the tables using command:
show tables;

However the same thing when I try from a remote m/c using java api it fails. Here is the code snippet that is failing.

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://RHDCN05.rmsi.com:10000", "", "");
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
```

Hope somebody can help in figuring out the problem.

Any help would be appriciated!!!

Comment: can you please add info about "failing": Show Exception, check your libraries and so on

Comment: did you check network connectivity? Like telnet `RHDCN05.rmsi.com 10000` ? While running manually - check your network connections (`netstat -a`) and looks for connections to RHDCN05.rmsi.com - might not be on port 10000 after all.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion, I revisited hive-site.xml and updated thrift port which solved my problem.<property>
    <name>hive.server2.thrift.port</name>
    <value>10000</value>
    <description>TCP port number to listen on, default 10000</description>
  </property>

Comment: Might I add this as answer then?